# forge viewer & BIM360 Docs viewer freezes when showing properties of dbId: 1

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-bim360

When loading a Revit file, we load the last 3D geom bubble, which is typical the last phase of a Revit model.
This gives us the most complete model.
Since the viewer update 3.37 "Property panel: support multi-selection" we experience freezing of the viewer when showing the property panel and no selection of elements. (properties of dbId 1 => project information )
This takes multiple minutes or crashes the viewer.

We get the same freeze when testing this in BIM360 Docs viewer , navigating to the phase view and show the property panel with no selection.

When loading another 3D view, everything works fine.

I don't see this behaviour on all of our Revit models, but typical the ones that have extensive project information.

Comment: Can you share the model with us for testing? please email cyrille at autodesk com

Comment: I shared a link to a model

Comment: @cyrille any confirmation or update on this?

Comment: I could reproduce the issue and reported the bug to the engineering team. They have fix the issue, and the fix should appear in the next update/version of the viewer.

Comment: I can confirm this issue is resolved with viewer rel 7.44